# List issue in IE when image floats left

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a list of items with text and an image that floats to the left. I want the text from the list to wrap around the image so that`s why i used float left on the image.

It works OK in Firefox and Chrome, but on Internet Explorer, the bullets or numbers from the list will not go next to the text, will go at the start of the line, over the image.

Check this [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/wovj80z0/11/) on Internet Explorer to see the issue. I test it on Internet Explorer 10 and 9.

The standard html code is this:

```
<img src="img_src" style="float:left">
<ol>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidit reque dicam vel in, eum dolore disputando et. Stet paulo no qui, mazim eirmod gloriatur vim te, nec commune intellegam id. Cu vis epicuri placerat, tractatos pertinacia vel ad, adipisci moderatius interpretaris nam ex. Per option minimum convenire cu, cum diam falli cu.</li>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vidit reque dicam vel in, eum dolore disputando et. Stet paulo no qui, mazim eirmod gloriatur vim te, nec commune intellegam id. Cu vis epicuri placerat, tractatos pertinacia vel ad, adipisci moderatius interpretaris nam ex. Per option minimum convenire cu, cum diam falli cu.</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: did you check my answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY THIS:

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2t8fuksz/)**

```
ol {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wovj80z0/7/)

added `float:left` for the `ol` the issue will be fixed and removed `padding`

```
ol {
    margin-left: 20px;
    float:left;
}
```

edit

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/wovj80z0/13/)

```
ol {
    padding-left: 30px; /* changed margin to padding */
    display: table-cell; /* added */
}
```

Comment: Please try adding more text to see what happens... The list will go under the image.